# How can i horizontally center this animation?

Tags: css, animation, alignment

I've got 3 images superposed for a css animation on a link hover. I'm using position:absolute for overlaying the 2 animated images. But then i don't know how i could center the animation on the page.

Here is the CodePen
http://codepen.io/beng_beng/pen/IHAFD

```
<div id="avatar">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/174x174" alt="rotator">
    <a id="rotator" href="#"><img src="http://s28.postimg.org/gfrse4h7d/small.png" alt="rotator"><span><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/j6qdwtowf/small.png" alt="rotator"></span></a>
</div>


body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#avatar img {
  position: relative;
  height: 174px;
  width: 174px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
a#rotator img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;  
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

a#rotator:hover img { 
-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-360deg); 
}

a#rotator span img {
position: absolute;
width: 147px;
height: 147px;
top: 14px;
left: 14px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;  
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

a#rotator:hover span img { 
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
```

Comment: looks like this is what you want http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AhHLx. You should add `position:relative` for the `#avatar` div, then just align the `#avatar` div, because it's just a normal div, you can use `margin:0 auto` to center it and of course its height should be smaller than the page's width so that it can be centered.

Comment: Please post your code within the body of the question. If CodePen goes down this question will be meaningless.

Comment: Ok I just added the code and will do it for further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#avatar {
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  width:147px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following trick to center images:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left:14px;
```

But changing the position of the parent object like King-King suggested is better.

```
#avatar {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:174px;
  position:relative;
}
```

According to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

> An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first
>   parent element that has a position other than static.